# Why I am getting NaN while trying to get sum of numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a new array which supposed to be an overall sum of numbers from the initial array(2 + 4 + 6 + 8).
However I get NaN. I don't understand why this is happening. It seems to me += operator doesn't work. I tried to use = instead of += and it worked(only for one iteration of course). Help me understand why += operator doesn't work in my case.

```js
const arr=[2, 4, 6, 8];
let newArr;
const sum = arr => {         
  for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {                          
    newArr += arr[i] + arr[i+1];                       
  }
   return newArr;     
};
sum(arr);
console.log('newArr', newArr);
```

Comment: do you want to get the total from the array or a new array with neighbor sums? please add the wanted result.

Comment: You are getting `NaN` because on the last iteration, `arr[i + 1]` is undefined (since it is outside the bounds of the array). The answers to this question make various assumptions about what the original intent of the code is. Please [edit] your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things: `newArr` must be initialized to zero, and the loop should only add one array element per iteration.

It would be cleaner to declare `newArr` *inside* the function, and then save the returned value somewhere.

```
    const arr=[2, 4, 6, 8];
    const sum = arr => {     
       let newArr = 0;    
       for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {                          
        newArr += arr[i];                       
       }
       return newArr;     
    };
    let total = sum(arr);
    console.log('total: ', total);
```

Answer (score 2):

`let newArr;` this undefined type by default it should be 0.

```js
const arr = [2, 4, 6, 8];

var bar;
console.log(typeof bar);

var newArr = 0;
const sum = arr => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    newArr += arr[i];
  }
  return newArr;
};
sum(arr)
console.log('newArr', newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a new array of summed numbers, you could take an empty array an iterate the values from

```js
const
    sum = array => {
        var sums = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) { // start from 1 keep index valid
            sums.push(array[i - 1] + array[i]);  // add predecessor and item
        }
        return sums;
    },
    array = [2, 4, 6, 8];

console.log(sum(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr=[2, 4, 6, 8];
let newArr=0;
const sum = arr => {         
       for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {                          
        newArr += arr[i];                       
       }
       return newArr;     
    };
    sum(arr)
    console.log('newArr', newArr);
```

Set The newArr at Zero and Delate The Second element in the function which is arr[i+1]
By The Way if You are Using the chrom dev Tool to check if the code is working well u will have some problems with the const keyword u will get an error syntax tell u that the variable is already declared u should delete the cash using the refresh button !